# perl mongodb complex structure update

Tags: perl, mongodb

I have this structure:

```
{
  "user" => "xxxx",
  "position" => 
  {
     "A1" => { "state" => 'It', region=>"LOM" etc etc..},
     "A2" => { .... },
     "A3" => { .... },
     ....
     "An" => { .. }
  }
}
```

insert is ok. but update return this error:

```
not a reference at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4/MongoDB/Collection.pm line 376
```

My update is:

```
$tbl->update({
{ _id => MongoDB::OID->new(value => "$id") },
       { '$set' => 
            { 
                "position" => 
                {
                    "A1" => { "state" => "En" }
                }
           }
        }
});
```

Where I wrong?
Thks!

Answer (score 1):

I check syntax of update source of [MongoDB::Collection](http://search.cpan.org/~kristina/MongoDB-0.45/lib/MongoDB/Collection.pm)

**syntax update**
`update (\%criteria, \%object, \%options?)`

**inside MongoDB::Collection method update**

```
sub update {
    my ($self, $query, $object, $opts) = @_;
    ...
}
```

but you pass only 1 parameter.

```
$tbl->update(
{  # 1st anonymous hash
   { _id => MongoDB::OID->new(value => "$id") },
   { '$set' => {                             
       "position" => {       
           "A1" => { "state" => "En" }
           }
       }
   } 
});
```

So I advice you figure out with passed parameters to method update.

Comment: $tbl->update(
   { _id => MongoDB::OID->new(value => "$id") },
   { '$set' => {                             
       "position" => {       
           "A1" => { "state" => "En" }
           }
       }
   } 
);   thanks!so it's correct! ;)